# ruby packing variables and monkey patching

Tags: ruby

Okay so this is the code:

```rb
    class Board
      attr_reader :size
    
      def initialize n
        @grid = Array.new(n) {Array.new(n,:N)}
        @size = n * n
      end
    
      def [] position
        row, col = position
        @grid[row][col]
      end
    
      def []= position, val
        row, col = position
        @grid[row][col] = val
      end
    
      def num_ships
        @grid.flatten.count(:S)
      end
    
      def attack position
        if self[position] == :S 
            self[position] = :H 
            puts "you sunk my battleship"
            return true
        else
            self[position] = :X 
            return false
        end
      end
    
      def place_random_ships
        max_ships = @size * 0.25
    
        while self.num_ships < max_ships
            row = rand(0...@grid.length)
            col = rand(0...@grid.length)
            position = [row,col]
            self[position] = :S 
        end
      end
    
    
    
    
    end
```

But,

```rb
def place_random_ships
        max_ships = @size * 0.25

        while self.num_ships < max_ships
            row = rand(0...@grid.length)
            col = rand(0...@grid.length)
            position = [row,col]
            self[position] = :S 
        end
      end
```

this works, and does what it's suppose to, but when I avoid packing [row,col] and add it directly it does not work.

```rb
def place_random_ships
        max_ships = @size * 0.25

        while self.num_ships < max_ships
            row = rand(0...@grid.length)
            col = rand(0...@grid.length)
            
            self[row,col] = :S 
        end
      end
```

I'm still new to programming, so please try to explain the issue to where I can understand it, or tell me the problem, so I can google it to get a better understanding please.

Comment: You're passing two different things to `[]`, in the first `place_random_ships` you're passing an array and destructuring in `[]`. In the second you're passing two values, not an array.

Comment: not 100% sure what you mean. Even if i try self[row][col] = :S it doesn't work. row = 0 col = 8 that would be self row 0 col 8 assign :S ------in my head that's how it works anyways still learning.

Comment: I mean you're passing different things to `[]=`. In `place_random_ships` ex #1 you pass an array, a *single value* (the array). In the second example you (attempt) to pass *two values* to `[]=` (actually three, since the second param to `[]=` is the value to set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you defined []= to take 2 argument,  and array and a value.

```
def []= position, val
    row, col = position
    @grid[row][col] = val
end
```

With your current implementation you would need to call it like this

`foo[[row,col]] = :S`

What you might want to to is define []= like this:

```
def []= row, col, val
  @grid[row][col] = val
end
```

then when you want to pass the array position you can use the array spread operator.  With this implementation both of these calls will work.

```
position = [1,2]

foo[1,2] = :S 
foo[*position] = :S
```

if you do that you probably would want to define [] the same way.

```
def [] row,col
  @grid[row][col]
end
```